# Cancel/stop next "Action" from triggering in Code by Zapier

Tags: zapier

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, if a certain condition is met, continue onto the next action with some data. If not, just stop.

According to the docs, all you have to do is return an empty array.

> If Code by Zapier is the Zap's trigger and you return an empty array
>   [], we will not trigger any actions downstream — it is as if you said
>   "nevermind" in code.

The problem is I'm doing that but the "downstream" action is still triggering and it's throwing an error since it, obviously, doesn't have the data it needs.

```
if (clients[inputData.email]) {
  return {
    name: inputData.name,
    courseName: inputData.courseName,
    price: inputData.price / 100,
    plan: inputData.plan,
    email: clients[inputData.email],
  };
}

return [];
```

Comment: strange! what's the id of your zap? I can take a look on our end.

Comment: On a Sunday night none the less, you're the real MVP. I believe the ID is 29981561 (according the URL parameter). @xavdid.

Comment: Weird! Looks like a bug. Your code should definitely be working. I've filed and i'll get back to you here when we know something (probably sometime tomorrow).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! So it turns out that this is working as intended. Per the docs you posted above (that can also be found [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-examples)), emphasis mine:

> If Code by Zapier is the **Zap's trigger** and you return an empty array [], we will not trigger any actions downstream — it is as if you said "nevermind" in code.

Since your code is an action downstream steps are always run unless there's an explicit error. The best way to handle this is with a filter. I'd follow up your existing code with a filter step that only continues if `name` (or something else that's always there) exists.

Sorry for that confusion! I'll probably bold or otherwise emphasize that line in the docs.

Comment: OMG zapier is amazing. Didn't even know "filters" existing. That'll work perfect. Thank you!

Comment: haha no problem. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!